# How MapView detect tap on overlay and disable another overlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I have two overlays in a MapView

overlay 1 - it is a subclass of Overlay and it draws a point where the user taps the finger using the onTouchEvent method.

Overlay 2 - it is a subclass of ItemizedOverlay, it has many itens. If the user taps one item it changes color (uses onTap method)

If the user taps a point where there is an iten of Overlay 2 it also draws the overlay 1.

What i want to do is, if there tap was on a item of overlay 2 it should not affect overlay 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `not affect overlay 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want to do is, if there tap was on a item of overlay 2 it should not affect overlay 1.

You have no control over when your overlays are told to draw. It is up to you to make sure that what you draw is what you want at all times.